# check an entered word by a user can be made from a given list of letters?

Tags: python, arrays, list, function

I have used this to randomly print a list of 7 letters.

```
import random

Tiles = open("tiles", "r")
Tiles = Tiles.readlines()
listoftiles = []
for x in Tiles:
listoftiles.append(x.split()[0])
for i in range (0,7):
mytiles = []
mytiles += random.choice(listoftiles)
print(mytiles)

outputs:
['E']
['X']
['W']
['X']
['O']
['W']
['I']
```

The variable 'word' then allows the user to input a word using the given letters above which are [E,X,W,X,O,W,I]

```
word = input("Enter word: ")

output:
Enter word: "..."
```

I need to create a function that accepts two parameters 'word & tile' then the function checks if that word can be made with the given letters above. The output should be true if the word can be made using the letters or false if the word cannot be made using the letters. So far this is what I have been able to do:

```
def checker(word,mytiles):
    for letters in word.split():
    if letters in mytiles == word:
        print("This word can be made")
        return True
print("This word cannot be made")
return False
```

output: `the complier doesn't run the code`

Even more context, this is a feature I want to add to complete a scrabble game I am making for a project.

Comment: watch out for indentation

Comment: has your question been answered?

Comment: what error does the interpreter report??

Comment: My complier doesn't return an output, could their be an issue with the code or my complier

Comment: When i tried to run the code, written in the comments. it seems to make sense the complier did not compute an output.                               
 def checker(word,mytiles):
    for letter in word:
        found = False
        for tile in mytiles:
            if letter == tile:
                found = True
                mytiles.remove(tile)
                break
        if found == False:
            return False
    return True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best course would be to loop each letter of the target word, and check with another nested loop if that letter exists in the tiles you have available. If it does, you remove it from the tiles, otherwise immediately return false, since even missing a single letter won't allow you to complete the word. If you reach the point where you search for a letter in the tiles but the tiles are empty, you still return false since you have no more tiles available to use.

Here:

```
def checker(word, tiles):
    for letter in word:
        found = False
        for tile in tiles:
            if letter == tile:
                found = True
                tiles.remove(tile)
                break
        if found == False:
            return False
    return True
```

This code will work if word is a string or a list, and tiles is a list of characters.